# Why people formally do this.$el.html() in the very first line of backbone view rendering?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

There's a Backbone.js view render function below:

```js
var bookListView = Backbone.View.extend({
  model: BooksCollection,

  render: function() {
    this.$el.html(); // lets render this view

    var self = this;

    for (var i = 0; i < this.model.length; ++i) {
      // lets create a book view to render
      var m_bookView = new bookView({
        model: this.model.at(i)
      });

      // lets add this book view to this list view
      this.$el.append(m_bookView.$el);
      m_bookView.render(); // lets render the book           
    }

    return this;
  },
});
```

I just came to know that people usually add `this.$el.html();` at the begining of the render function for rendering the view.

However, I have no idea why this code is used on the first line. It just works totally same, even though I remove the first line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That line you usually see is `this.$el.html('');`. Note the extra `''` which makes it a setter, rather than getter. It is used to clear the existing content in the view similar to `this.$el.empty()`. If it is not there, when you re-render the view to display changed data, the old data will stay in it, since it is a collection view to which items are just appended.

In the context of this particular example, let's say you have 2 books now and if the data changes to 3 books, you re-render this view - you'll have 5 books in it without the suspicious line.

As it is `this.$el.html();` doesn't do anything in the code you shared, but `this.$el.html('');` fixes a potential bug. I think you missed `''`

Comment: Hum... No. `this.$el.html()` would return the HTML content but do nothing. http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/x61hns01/ `this.$el.html('')`would clear the content.

Comment: @nikoshr oh... it should be `this.$el.html('')`

Comment: I agree but as stated, it's a no-op

Comment: Well, I just copied and pasted the code from a tutorial. Unfortunately, the tutorial codes have a little errors sometimes. Also, I am a totally new in Javascript and even couldn't guess what was the missing parts.

Because of you guys, now I can guess what was the missing part. Thanks